# Unsubscribe link in publicly viewed newsletter error

Tags: civimail

I was thinking (first problem) to use the "view in browser" url to build a link page for viewing past newsletters. If a user clicks on the unsubscribe link, the url "mysite.com/civicrm/mailing/unsubscribe?reset=1&jid=&qid=&h=fakehash" creates an error page:

*Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
Missing Parameters*

Looking for a cleaner redirect...

Answer (score 1):

I used a redirect since the url seems to be consistent for the web view.

Comment: hi, i have a similar issue, what do you mean by you used a redirect?

Comment: I just use the CMS redirect feature to redirect that link to my home page...it avoids the error. Sorry for my very late reply, I've not been active lately.